# Unable to upgrade to 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel

Trying to update to the newest LTS.

I run do-release-upgrade. I get not enough space message.

[image]

I then read about deleting old kernels so i followed the steps but it deleted nothing.

I then run this code to show the kernels installed.

```
dpkg -l | tail -n +6 | grep -E 'linux-image-[0-9]+' | grep -Fv $(uname -r)
```

Image of output of code:

[image]

The guide said that if it had rc next to it that it was already removed.

But running this: `df -h` returns:

[image]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt clean` as suggested by the first command? What about your personal files? Emptying the trash?

Comment: Yes, first thing I did before looking into kernals. I looked in the FTP and no personal files as far as I can see. It is very odd.

Comment: Instead of posting images, post the text and format it properly, please.

Comment: Your root partition is rather small at 20Gb. Consider enlarging it but recovering some space from other partitions.

Comment: I got a notification saying somone recommends to edit this so I did?

Comment: Is there a way of changing partition sizes while they are mounted?

Comment: No. You have to boot from a liveUSB and use gparted to modify the partitions. Make sure you have a backup of your files as this is low level tinkering.

Comment: Perhaps a ```sudo du -xh / | sort -rh | head -25``` to show us the top 25 largest files and directories? Please post it as text, not an image. But quite possibly your space is taken up by installed packages that you don't wish to remove.

Comment: You could also uninstall some big packages, perform the upgrade and reinstall them after.